# JQuery Checking and Unchecking Checkboxes validations

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes in which one is select all and other child checkboxes are there

this is my html

```
<label> Select All </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" checked="" id="parent">
<label> Child 1 </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="child" checked="" id="child">
<label> Child 2 </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="child" checked="" id="child">
```

This is my JQuery Script of checking and unchecking

```
 $('#parent').on('change', function () {
    $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));        
}); 
$('.child').on('change', function () {
$('#parent').prop('checked', false);
 $('.child').not(this).prop('checked', false);
$(this).prop('checked',true);   
});
```

The select all works fine but the ('.child') on change the parent is unchecked and the child remains checked, i cant uncheck

I need a way to for once any child is checked the parent should be unchecked along with all other child elements but also I should be able to select multiple children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `click` instead of `change`. Also change the `id="child"` to `class="child"`.

HTML:

```
<label> Select All </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" checked="" id="parent">
<label> Child 1 </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="child" checked="" class="child">
<label> Child 2 </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="child" checked="" class="child">
```

JS:

```
 $('#parent').on('click', function () {
    $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));        
}); 
$('.child').on('click', function () { 
     console.log($('.child').is(':checked').length);

    if ($('.child:checked').length == 2) {
        $('#parent').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#parent').prop('checked', false);
    }

});
```

```js
 $('#parent').on('click', function () {
    $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));        
}); 
$('.child').on('click', function () { 
  
 if ($('.child:checked').length == 2) {
  $('#parent').prop('checked', true);
 } else {
  $('#parent').prop('checked', false);
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Select All </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" checked="" id="parent">
<label> Child 1 </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="child" checked="" class="child">
<label> Child 2 </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="child" checked="" class="child">
```

Comment: ok but when i click child 2 the select all is also getting checked

Comment: Because you are selecting both (all) checkboxes.

Comment: ok I understood how it works but suppose i click child 1 when (all) is selected then it unchecks and if i make it checked in the code then it never unchecks is there a workaround for it

Comment: found the answer i was looking for after little tweaks

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are de-selecting the child checkbox again the first function is excuting and making the parent as selected. so you can try this:

```
$('#parent').on('change', function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('.child').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));  
    }else{
        $(this).prop('checked', false); 
    }
});
```